# how to possible private variable accessible in child class?

Tags: oop

I made a programme in oops concenpt there happening a private variable accessing in child class how it is possible. code entered below.....
here uis my code please help me how is it possible private variable in child class or please identify this code is correct or not.

```
<?php
class student

{
    private $sname,$srollno; //private variable
    public function Getdata($name,$rollno){

        $this-> sname=$name;
        $this-> srollno=$rollno;
    }

    public function Showdata(){

        echo "Name :".$this-> sname."<br>";
        echo "Rollno:".$this-> srollno."<br>";
    }
}

    $obj1 = new student;
    $obj1-> Getdata("Sandeep","26");
    $obj1-> Showdata();


    $obj2 = new student;
    $obj2 -> Getdata("Vivek","45");
    $obj2 -> Showdata();





class teacher extends student
{
    //private $tname,$troll;

    public function teach(){
        $this-> sname="tillu"; //here access private variable
        $this-> srollno="12";
    }

    public function teachShow(){
        echo  "tname :".$this-> sname."<br>";
        echo "troll : ".$this-> srollno."<br>";
    }

}

$obj3 = new teacher;
$obj3-> teach();
$obj3-> teachShow();

?>
```

Comment: I am having trouble trying to understand what you actually want. How are we supposed to know if your code is "correct or not" if you don't say what you expect the code to do.

Comment: i am taking two private variable in class student. can i access these variable in class teacher after inherit these property from class student."check my code"